# Can rest api allow not to install splunk forwarder?

Tags: java, rest, splunk

I have a task: investigate possibility not to install universal forwarder and use only java instead.
Can REST API (java sdk) allow to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "universal forwarder", but [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) isn't really an "API", its more of an architectural structure.  For example, commonly it is used in conjunction with [HTTP verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) like GET, PUT, DELETE, and POST to represent the common functions of lookup, inserting, deleting, and updating a record.  REST is supposed to be "Stateless", meaning you don't store any state on the server-side at all.

I personally prefer the REST approach to my web apps, and typically use JSON as my preferred transport format.  Spring MVC and Spring Roo can also be used to aid in building a RESTful web service.

If by "universal forwarder" you mean not using a servlet container, then the answer is "yes", but why would you want too?  You would would have to implement your own web server, basically, or some sort of socket management server, of your own.  There are alternatives to using Tomcat, like Jetty, and most servlet containers can be imbedded and extended if you don't want to run them externally.  I wouldn't recommend this approach, though, as its a lot of pain.

Comment: I mean Splunk universal forwarder (I mentioned it in subject)

Comment: Ok, so it looks like this Slunk thing is just a data aggregator of some sort.  So, short answer: Sure.  Long answer: Yes, you could write a custom application that provides a REST interface to allow you to read data from whatever this "Universal Forwarder" is reading and send it somewhere: some remote web service, a database, etc.  It would require you to write a lot of code, and possibly figure out how to interface with the Splunk application.  Basically, you are writing your own "forwarder".

Answer (score 1):

The Splunk Java SDK will definitely allow you to add data directly to a Splunk index.

General information including examples and getting started about the Splunk Java SDK is here:  http://dev.splunk.com/view/java-sdk/SP-CAAAECN

We don't have any examples right now that show explicitly how to load data into Splunk using the Java SDK - but if you drop a note to devinfo@splunk.com we can get one going for you.